# How do I create a socket connection with python 3?

Tags: python, sockets

The question says it all.

Context:

Imagine an URL route where I can type "Ping", press a button and the server answers "Pong" in pure Python 3?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a connection like this:

```
# create an INET, STREAMing socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# now connect to the web server on port 80 - the normal http port
s.connect(("www.python.org", 80))
```

Also you can get more information in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html).